# Dropdown menu not working in Wordpress, Uncaught TypeError: item.magnificPopup is not a function

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have been asked by a friend to look into a Wordpress site with a menu popup problem. See http://www.jaxsemperfidelis.org/.

It is using Cherry framework, magnific popup and sf-menu.

In the console the error message is:
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
Uncaught TypeError: item.magnificPopup is not a function
    at magnific_popup_init (custom.js?ver=1.0:169)

Cannot figure out what is going on.